# How to show that a set is not in PCP (Post Correspondence Problem)?

Tags: proof-writing, computational-complexity, formal-languages

In my lecture slides I have two examples of sets of tuples, where the first one is in PCP while the other one is not. The first is:

> $$PCP:=\{<(x_1,y_1)=(1,101), (x_2,y_2)=(10,00), (x_3,y_3)=(011,11)>\} \in PCP$$

The solution for this is $x_1 \cdot  x_3 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3=y_1 \cdot  y_3 \cdot y_2 \cdot y_3$. Since the set only has $3$ elements you can use a simple trial and error method and figure out a solution. However, what if the number of tuples is larger, let's say 9 tuples? How can you show that or rather proof that no matter the arrangement of the tuples, the set is not in PCP?

PS - Since PCP is not in NP, that means that one could write a program that could check whether a given set is in PCP. However, I am looking for a more mathematical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the PCP is undecidable. I.e., there is no general algorithm to decide if a PCP has a solution or not.

You could use some heuristics, or simply trial and error.

Comment: Then could you simply look at the last digits or each tuple and if there are no matching pairs (since the ending of the concatenated terms has to be the same), then the set is not in PCP? For example, if we have $(1,10),(10,1),(01,0),(0,001)$ you can see that the last digit of each term is never the same - therefore the set is not in PCP.

Comment: @SkiMask Being undecidable, this problem is similar to many other problems in mathematics. There is no algorithm which solves them all. This does not mean that some problems (or even some classes of problems) are not solvable. In your particular case, of course, the argument with the last digit works well. It is also true that, if the set is in PCP, a (fairly trivial) algorithm of searching for all possible sequences of indices (starting from shortest) will *eventually* find the solution. However, if the set is not in PCP, this algorithm will never halt.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Aha that makes sense. So I guess on a simple case by case basis, it wouldn't be hard to find a solution but as the complexity of the problem increases it becomes much harder to determine if the set is or isn't in PCP. Well actually since the algorithm will never halt if the set is not in PCP, it would become impossible since you wouldn't be able to distinguish a set that might be in PCP but is taking a long time or a set that is not in PCP.

Comment: @SkiMask It is not just about *that* algorithm never halting - it is also about any *other* algorithm not being able to solve it in general. Have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem#Proof_sketch_of_undecidability . Basically, if there was such an algorithm, you could use it to solve the halting problem (for a given algorithm decide if it will halt: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which itself is undecidable, because it could then give rise to another algorithm which halts if and only if it doesn't halt.